# How can I select rows from a table which are not linked to a different table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, combobox

I have 2 tables:

**users**

```
------------------------------------
| id (PK) | password | name | role |
------------------------------------
```

**dogs**

```
-------------------------------------------
| dogid (PK) | userid (FK : id) | dogname |
-------------------------------------------
```

I made a form where you can link a user to a dog, but every user can only have 1 dog. I made a combobox where you can select a user, to link it to a dog. This works

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN dogs ON users.username = dogs.userid WHERE users.role = 'dogowner' ORDER BY name";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<select id="gebrid" name="gebrid">
    <?php foreach($result as $pers): ?>
    <option value="<?= $pers['username']; ?>"><?= $pers['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

The code above selects all users with the role 'dogowner'. I want a second WHERE condition, which only selects users without a dog.

Is this possible, or would I have to change my database?

Comment: Basically, what you have created is that every dog can only have 1 owner (the opposite of your description). To match your description, I believe the foreign key should be on `users` and allow `NULL` (= condition to select users without dogs)

Comment: `INNER JOIN dogs ON users.username = dogs.userid` with the table structure shown this wouldn't work as there's no `username` in table `users`. I think `users.id = dogs.userid` would be correct

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` and add `dogs.userid IS NULL`

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN dogs ON users.id = dogs.userid 
WHERE users.role = 'dogowner'
  AND dogs.userid IS NULL
ORDER BY users.name
```

Comment: You will never have `dogs.userid IS NULL` with this DB and that `JOIN` though ...

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT userid 
                 FROM dogs)
```

This should give you all users that does not have an ID in the column userid in the dogs table.

Answer (score 0):

For your description (= 1 user can only have 1 dog), DB should rather be:

Users

```
------------------------------------------------
| id (PK) | password | name | role | dogid (FK)|
------------------------------------------------
```

Dogs

```
------------------------
| dogid (PK) | dogname |
------------------------
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE DogID IS NULL
```

Comment: So you would have a column for every animal a user can possibly have?

Comment: If there are more than dogs, I would rather have a table called `animals`. Not my point anyway. What I am not getting is the constraint written above **every user can only have 1 dog** (possibly, since nothing is written, every dog can be owned by 0, 1 or several users). Must be something I am missing, right? Happy to get the point if you have it.

Comment: ***I made a form** where you can link a user to a dog, but every user can only have 1 dog* - Nobody said this rule is forced upon in the DB. It is handled in the form.

Comment: But was it intended that a dog can have MAX 1 owner too?